# Self joins and Not in combined

Tags: sql, query-optimization, self-join

I need to write a query scanning 2 tables in a way that the record after self join in one table should not be present in second table if they have certain condition.

If an order is received we insert into UniqueReference Table that has unique constraints on reference combination (data1,data2,reference,identifier) 
But it could be that order get Rejected or Cancelled and next order might  come with same reference combination. I have to make sure I still allow it.

I give an example below for test data :

```
UniqueReference Table   
-------
sequence  data1  data2  key   reference  identifier  
1         XYZB   ABCD   234   Reference1   ID2
2         XYZB   DCBF   456   Reference2   ID2
3         XYZB   null   678   Reference3   null
4         XYZB   ABCD   980   Reference1   ID2 

Order Table
--------
sequence  key   status 
 1        234   Created  
 2        456   Rejected
 3        789   Processed 
 4        980   Cancelled 
 5        678   Processing
```

Now with above two data set when I receive an order (so say key 980) with reference combination (XYZB,ABCD,Reference1,ID2) then system should not allow that order (it is duplicate) because earlier we received such order with key (234) whose status is not Rejected. But if we receive new order with combination (XYZB,DCBF,Reference2,ID2) then we should allow this order because we do have that order in system but its status is Rejected.

I am needing something like

```
Select count(*) from Order o where o.status <> 'Rejected' and o.key in 
(select <self-join> on reference combination on key for newly received order)
```

Comment: please show expected output and also tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: If you have a unique constraint on those four columns, then you *cannot* allow a duplicate row.  Hence, I don't understand your question.  That unique constraint only knows about the first table, and doesn't care if another table says that the something is "rejected".  You would have to delete it or have additional columns in the unique constraint.

Comment: To avoid confusion, try to avoid using keywords as identifiers (`order,key,sequence`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mostly confusing yourself with this setup.
As for the `UniqueReference` table. If you say the combination `data1, data2, reference, identifier` is UNIQUE, well, then it should be just that: UNIQUE. It doesn't matter nor should care about what happens elsewhere.

Remark: I'm assuming the `key` field is unique too, and if it is, I do wonder why you don't simply use the autonumber/identity/... for it which you now seem to assign to the `sequence` column, which has no real value IMHO. Right now I can't tell how you produced these `key` values.

Now for the `Order` table, here you could foresee logic that says: if we don't have a previous record for this `key` yet, allow INSERT operation. If there is a previous one, find the most recent one and if it says 'Cancelled' then allow the INSERT too. Otherwise we always block the INSERT.

I'm not sure how you would like to do this, but I guess a stored procedure would make sense in this case.

PS: this code is far from perfect (for starters, it's NOT tested!), has no error-handling and probably can be optimized quite a bit (e.g. by merging certain operations, less branching, etc). But I think its verbosity makes it easier to read and since premature optimization is the root of all evil you might want to work it out like this first and optimize as needed when it turns out to be too slow.

(since you didn't mention RDBMS, I'm using T-SQL syntax, but I think it is sufficiently generic to run on most systems with minor tweaking...)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_insert_order (
                                  @data1        varchar(100), 
                                  @data2        varchar(100),
                                  @reference    varchar(100),
                                  @identifier   varchar(100),
                                  @status       varchar(100)
                                )
AS

    DECLARE @key          int,
            @is_new_key   bit,
            @allow_insert bit,
            @last_status  varchar(100)

    SELECT @key = NULL,
           @is_new_key = 0,
           @allow_insert = 0,
           @last_status = NULL


    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- do we already have a key for this combination?
        SELECT @key = [key]
          FROM [UniqueReference] WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
         WHERE data1      = @data1      
           AND data2      = @data2     
           AND reference  = @reference 
           AND identifier = @identifier

        IF @key IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SELECT @is_new_key = 1,
                       @key = 0 -- ??? -- I have no clue how you come up with these so I'm going to leave it open

                INSERT [UniqueReference] (data1, data2, reference, identifier, [key])
                VALUES (@data1, @data2, @reference, @identifier, @key)
            END

        -- do we allow insert?
        SELECT @allow_insert = @is_new_key

        IF @allow_insert = 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT TOP 1 @last_status = [status]
                  FROM [Order]  WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
                 WHERE [key] = @key
                 ORDER BY sequence DESC

                SELECT @allow_insert = 1
                 WHERE @last_status IS NULL
                    OR @last_status = 'Rejected'
            END

        -- do we do insert?
        IF @allow_insert = 1
            BEGIN

                INSERT [Order] ([key], [status])
                VALUES (@key, @status)

            END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    Return(0)
```

PS: Try to avoid using reserved words, `Order`, `key`, `status`, ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add `key` column in `UniqueReference` table to the unique constraint so it will be (data1,data2,reference,identifier,key)

Then you can use this query

```
;with
old_orders as (
    select distinct data1, data2, [reference], [identifier]
    from UniqueReference u
    where not exists(select top 1 1 from Order o where u.[key] = o.[key] and o.status in ('Cancelled','Rejected'))
)
insert into @UniqueReference (data1, data2, [reference], [identifier], [key])
select @data1, @data2, @reference, @identifier, @key
where exists (
    select @data1, @data2, @reference, @identifier
    except
    select * from old_orders o
)
```

With these values the insert will be rejected

```
declare 
    @data1 varchar(4)='XYZB',
    @data2 varchar(4)='ABCD', 
    @key int = 980, 
    @reference varchar(10)='Reference1',
    @identifier varchar(4)='ID2'
```

With these values the insert will be accepted

```
declare 
    @data1 varchar(4)='XYZB',
    @data2 varchar(4)='DCBF', 
    @key int = 999, 
    @reference varchar(10)='Reference2',
    @identifier varchar(4)='ID2'
```